# Wrong template function deduction

Tags: c++, templates, typename

Unexpected function deduction is happening in the following program. -

**Case I** -

```
template <typename T, typename>
void foo(T x, int) {
    cout << "In int foo\n";
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T x, char) {
    cout << "In char foo\n";
}

int main() {
    string s = "Hello World";
    foo(s, (int) 1);
}
```

Output

```
In char foo
```

**Case II** -

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x, int) {
    cout << "In int foo\n";
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T x, char) {
    cout << "In char foo\n";
}

int main() {
    string s = "Hello World";
    foo(s, (int) 1);
}
```

Output

```
In int foo
```

For case II, I just removed the last template parameter typename from the first function. Could someone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: in the first example there is no way for the compiler to figure out the second template parameter, why do you think it should be called? Or is it the second output that is unexpected?

Comment: in other words: What did you expect?

Comment: Did you meant `template <typename T, typename = void>
void foo(T x, int)`?

Comment: Please try to clarify what your question is.  "Explain what's happening" is **very broad** and I'm sure you're already familiar with many things that are happening in this code.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, I expected "In int foo" for both the cases, since I assumed that no type specified after typename would default to void type.

Comment: @Jarod42, right I need to explicitly specify.

Comment: @Drew Dormann, I saw a similar code and just wanted to understand the utility of template parameter typename without type

Comment: @SudeepAgarwal typename parameter without name is useful when doing class template specialization, sfinae and forward declaration of templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function,

```cpp
template <typename T, typename>
void foo(T x, int) {
    cout << "In int foo\n";
}
```

You tell the compiler that,

1. There are 2 template parameters.
2. The return is void.
3. Takes two parameters, one from type `T` and the other is `int`.
4. Then the function body.

When compiling `foo(s, (int) 1);`, the compiler knows the type of `T` as its given by the argument, the second argument is also given. But the second template argument is unknown. So the compiler tries to find the other most suitable one, which in this case the other `foo` function.

This time the compiler tests it out once again and it passes, as `int` can be implicitly converted to `char`. This is why it outputs `In char foo` in the first case.

In the second case, since there are no unknown types, the most suitable one is the first function `void foo(T x, int)`. That's because the second argument type is `int` and the function's second parameter types is also `int`.

To resolve the issue in the first case, you can provide a default type argument to the template. This way it knows the second type parameter, thus will work without an issue.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
void foo(T x, int) {
    cout << "In int foo\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit equivalent to this and be surprised by the result:

```
void foo(int a, int);
void foo(float b);

int main () {
    foo((int) 1); // calls the float version
}
```

Why does it calls the float version? Because you're missing the second int parameter! You simply just cannot call that version if you only send one parameter

Simply removing the second `int` parameter make it callable!

Same with with your code. Your function `foo` takes two template parameter, only one can be deduced, and you're not sending them to the compiler. Removing one will make it work. You could also set a default value:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
void foo(T x, int) {
    cout << "In int foo\n";
}
```

The compiler will be able to select this one, since it has a default value for the second template parameter you're not providing.